# Functor example

Tags: abstract-algebra, satisfiability

I am reading about Algebraic Structure and in the book say

> An algebraic structure, or simply structure, consists of a non-empty
>   set of objects existing in the world $w$, called the domain and
>   denoted below by $D$, and a function, called an interpretation and
>   denoted below by $R$, that assigns to each constant an entity in $D$,
>   to each predicate a relation among entities in $D$, and to each
>   functor a function among entities in $D$.

Looking for some example I found this in wikipedia:

The rational numbers $Q$ as σ-structures in an obvious way:
$\mathcal Q = (Q, \sigma_f, I_{\mathcal Q})$
where

$I_{\mathcal Q}(+)\colon Q\times Q\to Q$ is addition of rational numbers,

$I_{\mathcal Q}(\times)\colon Q\times Q\to Q$ is multiplication of rational numbers,

$I_{\mathcal Q}(-)\colon Q\to Q$ is the function that takes each rational number $x$ to $-x$, and
]
$I_{\mathcal Q}(0)\in Q$ is the number 0 and

$I_{\mathcal Q}(1)\in Q$ is the number 1;

In this example I understand what is a constant (1 and 0) but my question is: what is a functor? ***what is a predicate?***

Comment: Who? Are we talking about people here or abstract concepts?

Comment: abstract concepts

Comment: then it should be "what" not "who"